# Merge values of same key, in list of dicts

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I am relatively new to python 2.7, and can't figure out the following despite searching extensively on StackOverflow:

I have a `list` of `dict`s I wan't to combine, when key is the same, and add specific values (in the example `'price'`).

**Input:**

```
[{'id1': 'a', 'price': '2', 'color': 'green'}, {'id1': 'b', 'price': '5', 'color': 'red'}, {'id1': 'a', 'price': '2', 'color': 'green'}]
```

**Expected:**

```
[{'id1': 'a', 'price': '4', 'color': 'green'}, {'id1': 'b', 'price': '5', 'color': 'red'}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same idea as your question before the edit.

```
>>> data = [{'id1': 'a', 'price': '2', 'color': 'green'},
...         {'id1': 'b', 'price': '5', 'color': 'red'},
...         {'id1': 'a', 'price': '2', 'color': 'green'}]
```

Construct a temporary dictionary and accumulate values in it

```
>>> temp = {}
>>> for d in data:
...     if d['id1'] not in temp:
...         temp[d['id1']] = {}
...     temp_d = temp[d['id1']]
...     temp_d['price'] = temp_d.get('price', 0) + int(d['price'])
...     temp_d.setdefault('colors', set()).add(d['color'])
... 
>>> temp
{'a': {'colors': {'green'}, 'price': 4}, 'b': {'colors': {'red'}, 'price': 5}}
```

Then using list comprehension and dictionary comprehension, reconstruct the list of dictionaries.

```
>>> [{'id1': k, 'price': v['price'], 'colors': v['colors']} for k, v in temp.items()]
[{'id1': 'a', 'colors': {'green'}, 'price': 4}, {'id1': 'b', 'colors': {'red'}, 'price': 5}]
```

---

```
>>> data = [{'id1': 'a', 'price': '2'}, {'id1': 'b', 'price': '5'},
...         {'id1': 'a', 'price': '2'}]
```

Create a temporary dictionary where we can accummulate the sum of prices against their ids,

```
>>> temp = {}
>>> for d in data:
...     temp[d['id1']] = temp.get(d['id1'], 0) + int(d['price'])
... 
>>> temp
{'a': 4, 'b': 5}
```

Here we try to get the value of `d['id1']` from `temp` and if it is not found, 0 will be returned. We then add the `price` from the current dictionary and store the result back in the `temp` against the current id1.

Then reconstruct the list of dictionaries, with [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and dictionary comprehension, like this

```
>>> [{'id1': k, 'price': temp[k]} for k in temp]
[{'price': 4, 'id1': 'a'}, {'price': 5, 'id1': 'b'}]
```

Comment: Very nice. Only problem is that the first dict actually have another value, color, in one of the occurences  {'id1': 'a', 'price': '2', 'color': 'red'} How do I keep this in the final dict?

Comment: @DauleDK Will the color be the same for the given `id1` in all the dictionaries? For example, if `id1` is `a` and will the color be `green` always?

Comment: Not always, maybe is it possible to concatenate the values then?

Comment: @DauleDK Hmmm, you can make it a set of colors then, right? Remember: sets don't maintain duplicate values.

Comment: How would the answer look like, if the value never would change (I guess it is more simple then?)

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to compact the code like this:

```
import itertools as it
from operator import itemgetter

grupos = it.groupby(sorted(data, key=itemgetter('id1')), key=itemgetter('id1'))
res = [{'id1': v, 'price': sum(int(dicc['price']) for dicc in diccs) } for v, diccs in 
grupos]
print(res)
```

the output is:

```
[{'id1': 'a', 'price': 4}, {'id1': 'b', 'price': 25}, {'id1': 'c', 'price': 2}, {'id1': 'd', 'price': 1}, {'id1': 'e', 'price': 20}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not as nice as @thefourtheye but seems to work for me:

```python
di = [{'id1': 'a', 'price': '2', 'color': 'green'}, {'id1': 'b', 'price': '5', 'color': 'red'}, {'id1': 'a', 'price': '2', 'color': 'green'}] 

# Make a dict to hold new values!
newvals = {}

for d in di:
    for key, value in d.iteritems():
        if value.isdigit():
            if value in newvals:
                newvals[value] += int(value)
            else:
                newvals[value] = int(value)
        else:
            if value not in newvals:
                newvals[value] = value

for d in di:
    for nkey, nvalue in d.iteritems():
        d[nkey] = newvals[nvalue]

# Make a unique list of dicts
print {v['id1']:v for v in di}.values()

>>>[{'color': 'green', 'price': 4, 'id1': 'a'}, {'color': 'red', 'price': 5, 'id1': 'b'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
import collections 
from functools import reduce

data = [{'id1': 'a', 'price': '2', 'color': 'green'},
        {'id1': 'b', 'price': '5', 'color': 'red'},
        {'id1': 'a', 'price': '2', 'color': 'green'},
        {'id1': 'c', 'price': '2', 'color': 'blue'},
        {'id1': 'b', 'price': '5', 'color': 'red'},
        {'id1': 'b', 'price': '5', 'color': 'red'},
        {'id1': 'd', 'price': '1', 'color': 'white'},
        {'id1': 'b', 'price': '10', 'color': 'red'},
        {'id1': 'd', 'price': '20', 'color': 'yellow'}
        ]

valores = [list(item.values()) for item in data]
valores=[[item[0],int(item[1]),item[2]] for item in valores]

dicc = collections.defaultdict(list)
for item in valores:
    dicc[item[0]].append(item[1])
res=list(dicc.items())
res_def=[(t[0],sum(t[1])) for t in res]

colors=[dicc['color'] for dicc in data for item in res_def if item[0] == dicc['id1'] ]          
colors_unicos=reduce(lambda l, x: l.append(x) or l if x not in l else l, colors, [])
for lista in res_def:
    lista.append(colors_unicos.pop(0))

data_resultado=[{'id1':lista[0],'price':lista[1],'color':lista[2]}for lista in res_def]
```

the output is:
[{'id1': 'a', 'price': 4, 'color': 'green'}, {'id1': 'b', 'price': 25, 'color': 'red'}, {'id1': 'c', 'price': 2, 'color': 'blue'}, {'id1': 'd', 'price': 1, 'color': 'white'}, {'id1': 'e', 'price': 20, 'color': 'yellow'}]